# Script to zoom out iPhone's viewport?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, viewport

Is there any script to zoom out iPhone's viewport in Safari to initial scale = 1.0 upon clicking on some HTML element?

Like:

```
jQuery('#element').click(function(){
    //scale is set to default, 1.0 here (it zooms out as much as possible)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
```

will do what you are asking for. However, you need to check that you didn't prevent the user from scaling on click/drag like most mobile web app are doing.

Comment: But how do I apply that? Do I apply that to the body? To the viewport?

Comment: .css({"-webkit-transform": "scale(1.0)"})